# Should I create a method on NSArray to compare an array of a class I've created?

Tags: cocoa, nsarray, equality

I recently learned how to define an `isEqualToCustomClass:` to compare instances of that class (similar to `NSString`'s `isEqualToString:`).

Many times in my project I need to compare arrays of these objects. I consider them equal if and only if the counts are the same, and the custom objects at each location are the same (the order must be identical).

What is the correct way to make this available throughout my application? Should I subclass `NSArray` and add a custom `isEqualToArrayOfCustomThings:` ? Or a category? Or some other utility class that just takes two such arrays and compares them?

Comment: No. You should override the `isEqual:` method on your custom class itself.

Comment: Thanks. Why does NSString not take this path? And what if I still want a way to compare pointers? (I might not need this)

Comment: "Why does `NSString` not take this path?" - it does. - "And what if I still want a way to compare pointers?" - then you don't override `isEqual:`.

Comment: NSString has isEqualToString: for comparing the contents of the string tho right?

Comment: Yes, if you know that the object you pass in as its argument is an `NSString`. If you don't, then `isEqual:` is also overridden, and it basically yields `([other.class isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && [self isEqualToString:other])`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`-[NSArray isEqualToArray:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BABBHJBF) uses the `isEqual:` method of the array members to test equality with another array. If you prefer, `-[NSArray isEqual:]` will call through to `isEqualToArray:`.

All you need for this, then, is that `isEqual:` be implemented in your class.

N.B.: Apple advises that whenever you implement `isEqual:` for a class, you must also implement `hash` such that objects which compare as equal also have identical hashes. Mike Ash [goes into some detail on this](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-06-18-implementing-equality-and-hashing.html).

Comment: Doesn't `isEqual:`, if applied to two arrays, work the same as `isEqualToArray:`?

Comment: Yes, so far as I know, @MartinR, but I wanted to include a link to the docs, and `isEqual:` isn't explicitly listed in the `NSArray` reference. Do you think I should put that in the answer?

Comment: It is just something that I noticed (actually when comparing dictionaries). - Yes, it might be interesting to a reader how `isEqual:` works on arrays, but I would not advise you what to put in an answer!

Comment: Looks like `isEqual:` actually calls through to `isEqualToArray:`, @MartinR. I might have guessed it was the other way around.

Comment: Thanks - but I'm using my own method isEqualToSomeOtherObject for the custom objects, not overriding isEqual. It's cool though that NSArray relies on it contents' isEqual automatically.

Comment: So I guess you are suggesting I override isEqual instead? I tried this but it felt wrong - maybe I should try again. I think I stopped because, just like NSString, it's still useful to have a way to compare pointers. And I thought, if that's the way NSString does it (defining a new method, isEqualToString), then that's the way I should do it.

Comment: @BenPackard: You're mistaken. `-[NSString isEqual:]` doesn't do pointer comparison. `NSString * s = @"Dinsdale";
        NSString * t = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", s];
        
        NSLog(@"%d %d", s==t, [s isEqual:t]); // 0 (False) 1 (True)` Only the default `NSObject` implementation does. Any other class should use its content to determine equality with other instances of that class. You can always do pointer comparison with `==` if you need to.

Comment: Oh thanks. I think I was getting muddled thinking of == - so what is the point of isEqualToString? And does isEqual just call isEqualToString?

Comment: @BenPackard: I believe that it does. The class-specific `isEqualTo...:` methods can be ever so slightly faster because they can skip some initial checks, including the classes of the objects. There's also the readability value of `[aString isEqualToString:[anArray objectAtIndex:n]]`, for example.